# How to read specific lines from sparkContext

Tags: java, text, apache-spark, line

Hi I am trying to read specific lines from a text file using spark.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master);
sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("data.txt");
String firstLine = lines.first();
```

It can used the .first() command to fetch the first line of the data.text document. How can I access Nth line of the document? I need java solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache Spark RDDs are not meant to be used for lookups. The most "efficient" way to get the `n`th line would be `lines.take(n + 1).get(n)`. Every time you do this, it will read the first `n` lines of the file. You could run `lines.cache` to avoid that, but it will still move the first `n` lines over the network in a very inefficient dance.

If the data can fit on one machine, just collect it all once, and access it locally: `List<String> local = lines.collect(); local.get(n);`.

If the data does not fit on one machine, you need a distributed system which supports efficient lookups. Popular examples are HBase and Cassandra.

It is also possible that your problem can be solved efficiently with Spark, but not via lookups. If you explain the larger problem in a separate question, you may get a solution like that. (Lookups are very common in single-machine applications, but distributed algorithms have to think differently.)

Comment: If you go the take-get route with DataFrames, I think you need `lines.take(n).apply(n-1)`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that in a way. Assuming "`n`th" is zero-based :). `lines` is supposed to be a `JavaRDD` so `take` returns a Java `List<String>`, hence the `get` instead of `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this as fast as it gets

```scala
def getNthLine(n: Long) = 
  lines.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 == n).first
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Daniel Darabos said, RDDs are not indexed for line look ups, so an alternative method is to give it an index:

```
lines.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2==n).map(_._1).first()
```

Give it an index and then use the spark context first again, but this method is some what inefficient and silly for when the size of your RDD is small. BUT when the size of your RDD is very large, collecting it to the master becomes inefficient (and possible mem restraint), and this method becomes the better alternative.