# get specific row from spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any alternative for `df[100, c("column")]` in scala spark data frames. I want to select specific row from a column of spark data frame.
for example `100th` row in above R equivalent code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read specific lines from sparkContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221033/how-to-read-specific-lines-from-sparkcontext)

Comment: This is about DataFrames, and [How to read specific lines from sparkContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221033/how-to-read-specific-lines-from-sparkcontext) is about RDDs

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Firstly, you must understand that `DataFrames` are distributed, that means you can't access them in a typical **procedural** way, you must do an analysis first. Although, you are asking about `Scala` I suggest you to read the [Pyspark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame), because it has more examples than any of the other documentations.

However, continuing with my explanation, I would use some methods of the `RDD` API cause all `DataFrame`s have one `RDD` as attribute. Please, see my example bellow, and notice how I take the 2nd record.

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)], ["letter", "name"])
myIndex = 1
values = (df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
            .filter(lambda ((l, v), i): i == myIndex)
            .map(lambda ((l,v), i): (l, v))
            .collect())

print(values[0])
# (u'b', 2)
```

Hopefully, someone gives another solution with fewer steps.

Comment: Your link is dead. It should probably be this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame

Answer (score 20):

This is how I achieved the same in Scala. I am not sure if it is more efficient than the valid answer, but it requires less coding

```
val parquetFileDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("myParquetFule.parquet")

val myRow7th = parquetFileDF.rdd.take(7).last
```

Comment: Will the output change depending on how many nodes the data is clustered across?

Comment: the order is not guaranty, so the output might change on each run

Answer (score 16):

In PySpark, if your dataset is small (can fit into memory of driver), you can do

```
df.collect()[n]
```

where `df` is the DataFrame object, and `n` is the Row of interest. After getting said Row, you can do `row.myColumn` or `row["myColumn"]` to get the contents, as spelled out in the [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row).

Answer (score 9):

The `getrows()` function below should get the specific rows you want.

For completeness, I have written down the full code in order to reproduce the output.

```
# Create SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('scratch').getOrCreate()

# Create the dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)], ["letter", "name"])

# Function to get rows at `rownums`
def getrows(df, rownums=None):
    return df.rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] in rownums).map(lambda x: x[0])

# Get rows at positions 0 and 2.
getrows(df, rownums=[0, 2]).collect()

# Output:
#> [(Row(letter='a', name=1)), (Row(letter='c', name=3))]
```

Answer (score 6):

This Works for me in PySpark

```
df.select("column").collect()[0][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a scala way (if you have a enough memory on working machine):

```
val arr = df.select("column").rdd.collect
println(arr(100))
```

If dataframe schema is unknown, and you know actual type of `"column"` field (for example double), than you can get `arr` as following:

```
val arr = df.select($"column".cast("Double")).as[Double].rdd.collect
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do that by using below single line of code

```
val arr = df.select("column").collect()(99)
```

Comment: more like: .collect()[1][0], in case someone needs the help

Answer (score 2):

When you want to fetch max value of a date column from dataframe, just the value without object type or Row object information, you can refer to below code.

table = "mytable"

max_date = df.select(max('date_col')).first()[0]

> > ***2020-06-26***
> > instead of **Row(max(reference_week)=datetime.date(2020, 6, 26))**

Answer (score -2):

Following is a Java-Spark way to do it , 1) add a sequentially increment columns. 2) Select Row number using Id. 3) Drop the Column

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
..

ds = ds.withColumn("rownum", functions.monotonically_increasing_id());
ds = ds.filter(col("rownum").equalTo(99));
ds = ds.drop("rownum");
```

N.B. monotonically_increasing_id starts from 0;

Comment: `monotonically_increasing_id` - The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not **consecutive**.